# Scorpion in Injustice : Gods amongs us

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

I have been playing Injustice in my iPad for almost 2 months. Last week I got an update challenge to unlock Scorpion an Mortal Kombat character. I would like to know the link between Scorpion and the DC universe.

Comment: I think that there is absolutely no link between Scorpion and DC Universe except for 2 things: 1) There was a game MK vs. DCU; 2) MK9 and Injustice were both developed by Netherrealm Studios

Answer (score 4):

### Note: Spoilers for Mortal Kombat vs DC Universe possible

The link between Mortal Kombat and the DC universe is basically the game [Mortal Kombat vs DC Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_vs._DC_Universe).  However, there is a comic book that is a prequel to the game: [Mortal Kombat VS DC Universe: Beginnings](http://mortalkombat.wikia.com/wiki/Comic_Books#Mortal_Kombat_VS_DC_Universe:_Beginnings).

The story suggests that the Universe of Mortal Kombat began to merge with the DC universe into a world known as "[Earth-Mortal Kombat](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-Mortal_Kombat)".  The merging started with Darkseid and Shao Khan becoming [Dark Kahn](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Kahn_%28Earth-Mortal_Kombat%29) because of special conditions involving a malfunctioning [Boom Tube](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Boom_Tube) and Raiden's lightning.

As far as how Scorpion ends up back in the DC universe for Injustice, because [reasons](http://injusticegodsamongus.wikia.com/wiki/Scorpion#Intro.2FOutro).

Also, you can see a list of characters and locations from each Universe can be found [here](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_vs._DC_Universe:_Beginnings).

Comment: Mortal Combat in bold make my eyes bleed... (and in hyperlink too)